# J4 Get an array of parameters from template/module

Tags: php, module-params

The current Joomla implementation looks like

```
$moduleHelper->getParams()->get('paramName'); // don't remember this one perfectly
$app->getTemplate(true)->params->get('paramName');
```

Is there a way I can get an array of all parameters? I need to get them in an array ready to filter based on certain specification, something like this:

```
(array) $moduleHelper->getParams()->get('*');
(array) $app->getTemplate(true)->params->get('*');
```

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use field groups instead of prefixes to organize fields in the form. This way no additional code is needed:

```
<fields name="params">
    <fields name="logo">
        <field
            name="src"
            type="media"
            default=""
            label="TPL_EXAMPLE_FIELD_LOGO_SRC_LABEL"
        />
        <field
            name="alt"
            type="text"
            default=""
            label="TPL_EXAMPLE_FIELD_LOGO_ALT_LABEL"
        />
    </fields>
    <fields name="colors">
        ...
    </fields>
</fields>
```

To get an object containing all values from `logo` group:

```
$params->get('logo');
```

Specific fields can be accessed using dot separated notation:

```
$params->get('logo.src');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [an answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9920/get-module-parameters-using-loop) that explains the nature of the parameters and came up with a solution:

```
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;

$array_vars = array();
foreach(json_decode($params, true) as $k => $value) {
    if (strpos($k, 'my_setting_preffix_') !== false){
        $array_vars[$k] = $value;
    }
}
```

This is now exactly what I needed and the perfect solution to filter the outcome on the spot.

Cheers

Comment: `json_decode()` is unnecessary. `$params` here is a `Joomla\Registry\Registry` object which can be iterated.

Comment: In my code (templates/myTemplate/helper.php) I use `$registry = new Registry(); $registry->loadString($db->loadResult());` so `json_decode` is required. I don't exactly know which methods from which to use (Registry / Database [getDbo]) to not need to use `json_decode` but I know for sure my method works and is better for my exact need.

Comment: the $params is a `Joomla\Registry\Registry` object. You can get it n array format using the `Joomla\Registry\Registry::toArray()` function